# How long does it take to be deblacklisted from gmail

Tags: email, email-server

We provide a real estate agency in France with a mail server configured with poste.io.
In this change of semester, they have sent a high number of mails mails representing invoices, reminders, etc., with the help of a specialized software.
Obviously, this high sending rate did not please google which returns the following error:

> Error: Too many failures (Upstream error: 421 4.7.28 [xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
> 15] Our system has detected an unusual rate of 4.7.28 unsolicited mail
> originating from your IP address. To protect our 4.7.28 users from
> spam&undefined; mail sent from your IP address has been temporarily
> 4.7.28 rate limited. Please visit 4.7.28 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedRateLimitError to 4.7.28
> review our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines.
> d5-20020a056000186500b0020fc383d737si54567509wri.465 - gsmtp)

Ok. My client has sent too many emails. But I didn't not seen where google tells us what the limited rates are and for how long.
After identifying the problem and discussing with our client how to solve it how to solve it, we would like to make sure that our client can send back to gmail to gmail as before, and as quickly as possible. And above all, he would like to know how long the sending to gmail is blocked.

I specify that

- The ip address used is not blacklisted anywhere anywhere
- Our customer is the only one to use this ip address to send emails.
- The server postpones sending to gmail by putting it in the queue

Thanks in advance

PS: I am new. If I'm not on the right topic, please redirect me to the right forum

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not public knowledge how Gmail internally handles spam & blacklisting.

Comment: Ah Ok. 
Where can I ask this kind of question to get a quick answer? The google community doesn't seem to be fast and my client is getting impatient

Comment: Patience is a virtue, especially if dealing with Google. You won't get a quick answer to that question anywhere, no matter whom you ask, least of all from Google themselves.

Comment: As a technician, I agree. But if I put myself in the shoes of my client who has to send very important emails to gmail recipients, it's annoying. It's been going on for a week.  
Have any of you already experienced this problem? 
Do you have some tips to solve it? 
I could as a last resort change my IP address but is it a good idea?

Comment: The problem is solved. For your information, you have to wait 15 days. Thanks